# Existence of certain integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

So the question statement is simple.

Is there any 'large' prime $p$ such that $\phi(p^2)/2$ is odd?

Or weaker, is there any large integer $n$ where $\textbf Z_n^\times$ is cyclic and $\phi(n)/2$ is odd?

I can find out some small cases such as $\phi(7^2) = 2 \cdot 21$, but I cannot find ways to construct big ones nor disprove its existence.

By 'large' I mean, like if you have infinite of them then it can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: These are precisely the primes which are $3$ mod $4$, so yes, there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft what about integers not of $p^2$ form but also have cyclic multiplicative group?
And also could you show a brief explanation how it is precisely the $3 \mod 4$ case?

Comment: It's just a consequence of $\phi(p^2) = p^2 - p$. I might elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Integers with cyclic multiplicative group are (other than $2$ and $4$) those of the form $p^m$ for odd primes (and changing the exponent does not change anything here), and those of the form $2p^m$, which does not change the size of the multiplicative group, since $\varphi(2p^m) = \varphi(p^m)$ for odd primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Tobias Kildetoft's comment: given that $\phi(p) = p - 1$ (for $p$ prime) and that $\phi(p^2) = p^2 - p$ it follows that the parity of half $\phi(p^2)$ depends on $p \pmod 4$.

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $p^2 - p \equiv 1 - 1 = 0 \pmod 4$, which means that half $\phi(p^2)$ is still even. But if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $p^2 - p \equiv 1 - 3 = 2 \pmod 4$ and half of that is $1 \pmod 4$.

In Wolfram Mathematica, or Wolfram Alpha, try this: `Select[Prime[Range[25]], OddQ[EulerPhi[#^2]/2] &]` then input the results into Neal Sloane's OEIS. Oops, I forgot about 2. Indeed $\phi(4) = 2$ and half of that is odd. See https://oeis.org/A045326

So the answer is 2 and all primes congruent to 3 modulo 4. Which means that whatever the largest known prime is right now, most likely a Mersenne prime,  is probably a relatively big example of what you're loooking for.